# How to get previous row value in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to get previous row value of a dataframe.
Can you please help me how to do this?

example:

```
Dataframe:

and_or_not_oprtor
NULL
AND
OR
NULL
```

code

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
            if row['and_or_not_oprtor'] == None and row['operator_type'] == '=' and row['and_or_not_oprtor'].shift(1) == 'AND':
                case_stmnt = str(row['operator_type']) + "'" +str(row['input_value']) + "'" + ' ' + 'THEN' + ' ' + "'" + str(row['output_value']) + "'" + ' '
            elif row['and_or_not_oprtor'] == None and row['operator_type'] == '=':
                #print('shiv')
                case_stmnt += 'WHEN' + str(row['operator_type']) + "'" +str(row['input_value']) + "'" + ' ' + 'THEN' + ' ' + "'" + str(row['output_value']) + "'" + ' '
```

error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shift'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: You have `row['and_or_not_oprtor'].shift(1)` and since `row['and_or_not_oprtor']` is `NULL` for the first row, `row['and_or_not_oprtor']` will evaluate to `None`. So what you're really stating is `None.shift(1)` which obviously won't work and is exactly what the error message is telling you. What exactly is the question?

Comment: @Grismar Hi Sir.. Actually i want to check previous value of same column. Can you tell me how to do this? Suppose code is iterating in 7th row and i want to check 6th row value then how to do this?

Comment: By, for example, keeping a copy of the previous row's value and updating it after each iteration - I suggest writing some code that tries doing it and post a new question that's actually about the question you want to ask, instead of posting a broken piece of code that seems to have very little to do with the problem you need an answer to.